# Uber or similar in Spain and in general

Tags: uber

I will be travelling from Touleouse to  Pont de Suert in Spain soon.  It seems public transport is not so regular all the way.

I know if Uber works in similar ways to other countries I have been to it will be OK

Is there some way I can have an idea about how easy it is, and the cost (Compared to other countries and in general)?

Are there similar modern services that can be appropriate?

I think it might need for 1 Hour.  Rome2rio estimates taxi costs at around 100€

Comment: I am not sure I follow your question.  Are you looking for list of services similar to Uber?

Comment: I would like to have some idea about how easy it is to get a ride, and the costs.

Comment: Why not just launch Uber and put in your start point and end point and just check.  I am not sure I follow what it is you're looking for.  There are no aggregators for ride share sites since payment is dependent on distance.

Comment: According to google map, toulouse to pont de suert by car is about 3 hours (in good weather);  what is the 1 hour for ?

Comment: @Max: Google Maps travel time estimates are not really reliable, although they usually do present a lower bound in my experience (at least in Germany, the indicated time typically has to be multiplied by 1.5).

Comment: the road selected by google is a simple 2 way mountain road so I would be confident that it will take more than 2 hours to drive; straight line distance is around 95 miles, so with the road taken, I would nearly double that.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper This only strengthens Max's point...

Comment: Parts of the route is covered by frequent trains and buses.  So 1 hour is what I think I can't have easily covered

Comment: @Relaxed: That was exactly my intention, while pointing out that the 3 hours as such should not be taken at face value.

Comment: I can get Uber-estimates from Toulouse, but it should be better to take the train the first part. and it is difficult to know where I might end, and if I can an Uber from there.

Comment: that is the point no ? make it simple and pay a little more to know the itinerary and time it takes; instead of adding unknown variables.

Comment: See comment as response to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you rent a car and drive yourself to your destination ? is it a round-trip the same day or multi-day service?

You could rent a "voiture de tourisme avec chauffeur" (VTC) (similar to a limousine service) to drive you there.

I believe for such an unusual destination ( at least from Toulouse), you'd better get direct quotes from taxi and VTC services.

A quick search would set you back at least 300 euros one-way, if not more. (about the same thing for Uber)

for example :

http://www.taxiproxi.fr/estimer-et-reserver-votre-taxi-entre-toulouse-et-el-pont-de-suert-spain-le-jour

Comment: In the end I "took the chance" and had to wait 2 hours at a small French station.  In the end it cost me around €70 to cross the border and reach the Spanish public transport system..  (I didn't feel like calling in French to local taxi companies for quotes).  Its the kind of thing I could have   handled better if I had known more about travelling in France.  About Uber: in France it does exist, but not the coverage I am used to.  In Spain it seams easy to get a taxi, in Barcelona it seems the taxi companies worked a bit like Uber, with their own apps etc.